# How to query WURFL information

Tags: wurfl

What is the programming interface to querying device capabilities in wurfl?

Comment: The WURFL FAQ on the WURFL website exactly addresses this point: http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/faq.php#210

Answer (score 3):

WURFL Creator here. ScientiaMobile recently launched a new way to make WURFL available to developers. I advise you check out http://wurfl.io/

In a nutshell, if you import a tiny JS file:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="//wurfl.io/wurfl.js"></script>
```

you will be left with a JSON object that looks like:

```
{
 "complete_device_name":"Google Nexus 7",
 "is_mobile":true,
 "form_factor":"Tablet"
}
```

(that's assuming you are using a Nexus 7, of course) and you will be able to do things like:

```
if(WURFL.form_factor == "Tablet"){
    //dostuff();
}
```

This is what you are looking for.

**Edit May 2023:**
This comes a lot of years later, but it really adds a new dimension to my original answer. ScientiaMobile recently launched a new product (which includes a free version) called WURFL Query REST API (or QuWURFL for short) that exactly addresses the question. Not only can you query WURFL with a full set of HTTP headers, but you can now also create fully-fledged queries based on WURFL capabilities and their values.

https://docs.scientiamobile.com/documentation/cloud/getting-started-with-wurfl-wurfl-query-rest-api

You can now ask questions like "give me all tablets released by Motorola between 2010 and 2020". Using this service in connection with the aforementioned WURFL.js might be a great way to integrate device intelligence into an app or a customer-facing web application.
Just like WURFL.js, also QuWURFL offers both a free and a premium version.

*Disclaimer: I work for the company that offers this free service. Thanks.*

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Tera-WURFL for PHP & MySQL.  Check it out at [the Tera-WURFL Website](http://www.Tera-WURFL.com).

Answer (score 1):

For Python, I recommend [pywurfl](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywurfl/).  You can read more on how to use it [here](http://celljam.net/).

Comment: That library belonged to a time before WURFL was offered by ScientiaMobile with a commercial license. the right resource for those who want how to query WURFL from Python is this: https://docs.scientiamobile.com/documentation/infuze/infuze-python-module-user-guide

Answer (score 0):

There are APIs for Java, PHP and .NET, all listed in a rather chaotic fashion [here](http://wurfl.sourceforge.net/). I know the Java API is pretty good, I have no idea how good the others are.

Answer (score 0):

Depending to the language you will use. The official java,php and .NET api are pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

A simple .NET Wurfl api example:

```
    protected virtual IDevice GetDeviceInfo(string userAgent)
    {
        IWURFLManagerProvider<IWURFLManager> wurflManagerProvider = new WURFLManagerProvider();
        IWURFLManager wurflManager = wurflManagerProvider.WURFLManager;
        return wurflManager.GetDeviceForRequest(userAgent);
    }
```

More importantly, once you have the info, how reliable is it and **what capabilities are useful**?

Answer (score 0):

For .NET, we've been using the 51degrees solution here: [51 Degrees](http://51degrees.mobi)

Keep in mind that the WURFL licencing has recently changed in case it applies to you.